# Values not being stored in a vector - not sure what's going on here

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem where I have to store some values in a vector nested in a map, but the values aren't being stored. The map structure is `Map <Vector<char> >`

I'm trying to paste only the code that is appropriate to the problem is it is situated in a larger context, but I suspect I'm missing something important. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDITS: I am using Stanford CS106B libraries in this question which provide interfaces for Map, Vector, getValue and add:

```
     * Constructor: Map
     * Usage: Map<int> map;
     *        Map<int> map(500);
     *        Map<string> *mp = new Map<string>;
     * -----------------------------------------
     * The constructor initializes a new empty map. The optional 
     * argument is a hint about the expected number of entries
     * that this map will hold, which allows the map to configure 
     * itself for efficiency at that size.  If not specified, a 
     * reasonable default is used and the map will adapt as entries 
     * are added. The explicit keyword is used to prevent  
     * accidental construction of a Map from an integer.
     * Raises an error if sizeHint is negative.
     */
    explicit Map(int sizeHint = 101);


     * Constructor: Vector
     * Usage: Vector<int> vec;
     *        Vector<student> dormlist(200);
     *        Vector<string> *vp = new Vector<string>;
     * -----------------------------------------------
     * The constructor initializes a new empty vector. The optional 
     * argument is a hint about the expected number of elements that
     * this vector will hold, which allows vector to configure itself
     * for that capacity during initialization.  If not specified, 
     * it is initialized with default capacity and grows as elements 
     * are added. Note that capacity does NOT mean size, a newly 
     * constructed vector always has size() = 0. A large starting 
     * capacity allows you to add that many elements without requiring 
     * any internal reallocation. The explicit keyword is required to 
     * avoid accidental construction of a vector from an int.
     */
     explicit Vector(int sizeHint = 0);
```

getValue is in the Map interface, so is add for both of them...

```
     * Member function: getValue
     * Usage: value = map.getValue(key);
     * ---------------------------------
     * If key is found in this map, this member function returns the 
     * associated value.  If key is not found, raises an error. The
     * containsKey member function can be used to verify the presence 
     * of a key in the map before attempting to get its value.
     */
    ValueType getValue(string key);
```

And add for both map and vector...

```
     * Member function: add
     * Usage: map.add(key, value);
     * ---------------------------
     * This member function associates key with value in this map.
     * Any previous value associated with key is replaced by this new
     * entry. If there was already an entry for this key, the map's
     * size is unchanged; otherwise, it increments by one.
     */
    void add(string key, ValueType value);


    /*
     * Member function: add
     * Usage: vec.add(value);
     * ----------------------
     * This member function adds an element to the end of this vector. 
     * The vector's size increases by one.
     */
    void add(ElemType elem);


/* Private Instance Variables */
int seed_length;
char letter;
//Map <Vector<char> > map;

/* Function Prototypes */
string promptUserForFile(ifstream & infile);
char nextCharacter(char letter);
void storeInVector(string sequence, char letter, Map<Vector<char> > map);

int main() {

ifstream infile;
promptUserForFile(infile);

// Ask what order of Markov model to use.
cout << "What order of Markov model should we use? ";
cin >> seed_length;

// Store sequences in a map.
string sequence;
Map<Vector<char> > map;

for (int i = 0; i < seed_length; i++) {

    letter = infile.get();
    sequence += nextCharacter(letter);

}

while (infile.eof() == false) {

    letter = infile.get();
    storeInVector(sequence, letter, map);

    sequence.erase(0,1);
    char next_letter = nextCharacter(letter);
    sequence += next_letter;

}
}
```

And the function storeInVector is what's causing the problem...

```
void storeInVector(string sequence, char letter, Map<Vector<char> > map) {

cout << sequence << endl;
cout << letter << endl;

Vector<char> vector(200); // I tried to specify size because it wasn't being populated... so I thought this may help

if (map.containsKey(sequence)) {

    // Insert the sequence that comes after it into the vector.
    map.getValue(sequence).add(letter);

} else {

    // Create a new key and vector.
    map.add(sequence, vector);
    map.getValue(sequence).add(letter);

}
}
```

Comment: Yes, please show us the relevant part of the definition of `Map`, e.g. `getValue` and `add`.

Comment: Also add the non-standard function of add/gerValue

Comment: You probably need to pass the map by reference into the method; you're adding the char to a copy made when the parameter is passed by value.

Comment: There might be other nastiness waiting in this code since you seem to have `using namespace std` somewhere (e.g. since you have just `ifstream`), but are naming a variable `map` which is also in `std`.

Comment: Hi there. My apologies, I may have left out some valuable bits in trying to shorten the question. Editing the question now...

Comment: Changed now... I am using Stanford CS106B libraries/interfaces, so the following are included in the file: #include "genlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "map.h"

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill This is what I suspected might be the problem but putting & in front of the map brings up an error. Where should I place it so it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `map` by reference: `void storeInVector(string sequence, char letter, Map<Vector<char> >& map)`.

As the the code is, every call to `storeInVector` will create a copy of Map >, and your original will keep untouched.

EDIT:

Do not forget to change the function declaration too (thanks to @user3175411)

Comment: When I try to pass the map by reference, it gives me an error that says "Symbol Not Found": Undefined symbols:
  "storeInVector(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char, Map<Vector<char> >)", referenced from:
      Main()    in assignment_2_part_1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found

Comment: @marchon How are you linking these libraries?

Comment: Right above all the declarations/function prototypes, I've got them included: #include "genlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "map.h"

Comment: You have to change the function declaration too.

Comment: @marchon This could be not enough in C++. Unless you are sure that these includes have templates for the function (or even the implementations). You most show the linker where the static or dynamic libraries are, so it can find the implementations. And try what user3175411 cited. I´ll complement the answer.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita I've added using namespace std; and that doesn't make a difference either. Changed function declaration to: void storeInVector(string sequence, char letter, Map<Vector<char> > & map); <-- is that what you mean? Does it also need to be in the parameters, e.g. storeInVector(sequence, letter, & map);

Comment: @marchon yes. No! The `&` should go only in function signatures. If you put this when calling, you will pass the address, not a reference. Then call just `storeInVector(sequence, letter, map);`

Comment: Strange thing is when I add the following lines to see if it is even creating a vector at all using the functions storeInVector, it gives an error saying that there is an error getting a value at the index of 0 in a vector of size 0? Any clues? This is what I added after the else in that function... char ch = map.getValue(sequence).getAt(0);
  cout << ch << endl;

Comment: @wesley.mesquita Not using the ref in the parameters... same problem.

Comment: Strangely, I've managed to get it working. For some reason all of my vectors have to be initialised up to a certain value for it to work. However, I think passing by reference was also a huge problem in the code. Thank you, @wesley.mesquita for your help.

Comment: My advice at this point: make a very thiny test case (just `main` and `storeInVector`, no `ifstream` and no prompts). Inserting one by one the elements in yout map. Debug the `storeInVector` step-by-step.